# How to send simple Timeline message for google glass

Tags: google-mirror-api

How can i post simple timeline message to glass with REST client. I have access token for the user. can any one please help. Thanks in advance.

I am getting following response in json format

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
            "message": "Insufficient Permission"
        }],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you providing the access token as part of the rest call? You should provide it as part of an `Authorization` header indicating you have a bearer token. So the full HTTP request might look something like this, assuming your access token was "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"

```
POST /mirror/v1/timeline HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 26

{ "text": "Hello world" }
```

See https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline for this example and more details.

If you are trying to do this with curl, your command might look something like

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" \
  --header "Content-type: application/json" \
  --data '{ "text": "Hello world" }' \
  https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline
```

It is generally best to use one of the libraries, which will help manage authentication for you. Is there a reason you're using raw HTTP/REST?